# Looking for an old image of designing a CPU with plan laid out / being edited on a literal floor

Tags: history

There is an image that I remember seeing, but that I have never been able to find. It shows 2-3 people on their hands and knees, crawling around a blueprint of a chip that had been rolled out over the floor of a room. Presumably this was from before computers had enough memory / processor power to supersede working with physical artifacts representing the design.

I'm probably mismembering the fine details (e.g. was it a CPU? how many people were there? did it actually cover the whole floor?).

Does anyone know the image I'm referring to, or have a link to it?

Comment: Perhaps google up "rubylith?"

Comment: Are you perhaps referring to the photo in this question? [What are these engineers doing sitting on a large format drawing of B-47s aircraft?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/55041/what-are-these-engineers-doing-sitting-on-a-large-format-drawing-of-b-47s-aircra/)

Comment: Rubylith in 1970 was about 4 mm, I think. Anyway, you can check out the first image on this page: [rubylith layout](https://www.quora.com/How-do-they-design-the-layout-for-microchips-if-they-have-billions-of-transistors).

Comment: @jonk The wikipedia article on rubylith says "The physical layouts of the first generations of Intel microprocessors (the Intel 4004[2] and the Intel 8008 (nee 1201)) were first hand drawn on graph paper. A technician would then use a coordinatograph to precisely cut the rubylith and a knife". I think I'm looking for a picture of a super-sized graph paper instead of the rubylith.

Comment: @GregHewgill No, that's not the image. But the aesthetic is certainly very similar.

Comment: @CraigGidney Ah. I misunderstood.

Comment: There is a picture matching the description, Figure 12.13 on page 851 in The Art of Electronics, 2nd edition. Check it out if you can find a copy of the book.

Comment: @Justme https://archive.org/details/TheArtOfElectronics-2ndEdition/page/n853

Comment: @Justme With snip-n-snails help, make that an answer please...

Comment: something like [this](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/55041/14213) except not airplanes

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I suspect you may be thinking of a short scene from either [The Day the Universe Changed](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0199208/?ref_=fn_al_tt_1) (unlikely) or [Connections](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0078588/?ref_=fn_al_tt_1) (more likely). James Burke visited Bell Labs and there is a scene where you see several engineers working on a chip design on the floor exactly as you describe. I'm sure it's not the only example, but it is a well-viewed one.

Comment: Do you have a link for that second reference? [IMDB has several mentions](https://www.imdb.com/find?ref_=nv_sr_fn&q=connections&s=all) for that title. Also, who's *he*?

Comment: I *have* watched Connections. You don't happen to know which episode this scene is in?

Comment: @JanDoggen "He" means the host of *The Day The Universe Changed* and *Connections*: James Burke.

Answer (score 23):

Maury Markowitz's answer was correct, it was actually a *scene* and not a picture. I was able to find it in "The Day the Universe Changed" Episode 1 "The Way We Are: It Started with the Greeks". It's around 34 to 35 minutes in (well... it might depend on the version you're watching).

- You can find the episode [on the internet archive](https://archive.org/details/thedaytheuniversechangedIitstartedwithgreeks/thedaytheuniversechangedIitstartedwithgreeks/thedaytheuniversechangedIitstartedwithgreeksreel2.mov). It's in two pieces (two "reels"); the relevant moment is `12:38` to `13:03` of reel 2.
- Found also in Daily Motion:  https://www.dailymotion.com/video/x6cr0hv after about `36:00` starting with (what looks like) Bell Labs' Holmdel building.

[image: Screenshot from The Day the Universe Changed]

Comment: For anyone who has not watched this series, you don't know what you're missing.

Comment: @MauryMarkowitz absolutely!